# Trouble importing Pandas

Tags: pandas, import, built-in

I am using the Anaconda distribution on Win7 - when I run python through the powershell I can import pandas and numpy without issue.  However, when I run it through sublime (as i do on all my other machines by using a build system that targets the python executable), I get `ImportError: No module named builtins`

Here is the full detail:

`No module named builtins
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jarjarbinks\Sublime Text Build 3065\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd 
  File "C:\Users\jarjarbinks\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "tslib.pyx", line 40, in init pandas.tslib (pandas\tslib.c:63148)
  File "C:\Users\jarjarbinks\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    import builtins
ImportError: No module named builtins
[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['C:/Users/jarjarbinks/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda/python.exe', 'C:\\Users\\jarjarbinks\\Sublime Text Build 3065\\test.py']]
[dir: C:\Users\jarjarbinks\Sublime Text Build 3065]
[path: C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Hyland\Web ActiveX\;C:\Users\jarjarbinks\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda;C:\Users\jarjarbinks\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\Scripts]`

No clue on this one, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Never seem that before, but `import builtins` @line 51 is in a `try...except` block, which suggest some imports in the `try:` block didn't work. My 2c.

Comment: Yah I checked that out yesterday -- looks like it's related to using \__builtins\__ vs builtins for 2.7 v 3.0 compatability.  In any event, situation resolved itself when I moved the file I was trying to run out of Sublime's folder (not sure why it was there or why that helped, but I'll take it!).

Comment: Such problems might appear, if you have multiple Pythons in your system. One could be from anaconda, another installed system-wide and if the problem appears only in Sublime, I would check, which Python it is going to use (probably picking wrong one).